# Compare two strings in Java and show the character differences

Tags: java, string, comparison, character

I'm looking for a way to compare two strings to each other character by character.

It should show whether there are other characters which don't appear in both strings.

Does someone have a solution for?

```
 for(int j=0; j < min; j++) {
          s1 = w1.substring(j,j+1);
          s2 = w2.substring(j,j+1);

          if (!s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) ){
            counter++;    
            
          }
        }
```

This only looks sequential for differences. But I want to find out whether there are differences between those two strings at all.

```
 So **abc** and **cab** should count as a hit
```

Comment: Inefficient? In what way?

Comment: You should define more clearly what you actually want to achieve. *"im looking for a way to compare two strings to each other character by character"* then *"i want to find out whether there are difference between those two strings at all"*. So "character by character" or "difference ... at all"? Completely different things.

Comment: This strikes me as a "Gimme teh codez" type question. What solutions have you already attempted? What is it that didn't work in those attempts? Can you provide a sample input set and what the output for each input should be? As is, it's very hard to understand what effort you've put into finding the solution yourself, and harder to understand what answer you actually want given the relatively vague requirement statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to show that 2 strings have the same letters and the same amount of each letter.  Use 2 hashsets, where the key is the character and the value is the number of occurrence in the string.  you'll have one hashset for each string, then loop through the string add the characters to the set and compare to see if the sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Turn them into charArrays and add the differences to an empty string as a for loop scans through them, for instance

```
String a = "abc";
char[] aa = a.toCharArray();
String b = "cba";
char[] bb = b.toCharArray();
String dif;

public void differ() {
  for(int i = 0; i < aa.length - 1; i++) {
    if(!aa[i].equals(bb[i])) {
      dif += aa[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I believe running differ() would return "ac" because they both have b in the middle. Is this what you wanted?